# Why Doesn't the Amount of Work Determine the Elastic Potential Energy in Springs and Gravitational Potential Energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy, spring

Why isn't the amount of work done on the spring the determining factor for the amount of elastic potential energy stored in a spring?

I learned that the change in potential energy is a result of the work done on the object. Therefore, this should imply that if a spring is stretched with a small amount of force and then stretched to the same extent with a larger amount of force, the elastic potential energy acquired by the spring in its elongated state should vary.

However, this does not seem to be the case in reality. The potential energy of a spring, regardless of the amount of work done on it, is always the negative of the work done by the spring force on the spring, i.e., *$\frac{1}{2}$ k x²*.

Similarly, why does the gravitational potential of an object depend only on its height above the ground and not the work done to bring it to that height? In other words, shouldn't the amount of force applied affect the work done on the object, and therefore, the work done on the object by the agent in raising it to that height should also be the determining factor?

Also, where does the extra energy go if the work done on the object by the agent is more than what gets stored as in the case of spring?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you assume the work done when you apply a force to something can only go into the potential energy. If there is a net force on an object, it will accelerate, and gain *kinetic* energy.

In order to answer your question about the spring I need to imagine a massless spring attached to the wall on one side and a small mass $m$ on the other side. You apply your force to the small mass $m$.

If we just had a massless spring, then nothing you proposed would make sense. A massless spring, when you apply a force $F$ to it will instantly elongate to a length $l=F/k$, where $k$ is the spring constant. If you want to apply different forces for different amounts of time, we need to put a small mass so these kinds of questions make some sense.

Indeed the work done on the spring plus small mass is force times length. So if I apply a force $F$ to the small mass over a distance $l$, then I have put an energy $E_{\text{total}}=Fl$ into the system. But the energy in the spring is $E_\text{spring}=kl^2/2$. So if I'm free to apply a bigger force, where does the extra energy go? It goes into the mass' kinetic energy.

In the beginning, you apply your force $F$. The spring is applying no force in the beginning. So the mass accelerates at a rate $F/m$. As the spring elongates (length $x$) it starts to apply a force $kx$ in the opposite direction. So the net force as a function of distance is $F-kx$. We integrate this over the distance that you apply the force $l$ to find the net work done on the mass (and thus it's kinetic energy). We find the expected result $Fl-kl^2/2$.

In summary, if you apply more force than a spring pulls back, you accelerate the end of the spring, adding kinetic energy to the end of the spring. So you don't just put energy into the spring's potential. Likewise, a rocket (for example) applies more force upward on itself than gravity pulls it down. That's why it accelerates upward! And since it has gained speed, it has gained kinetic energy - not just gravitational potential energy.